# Concurrency in java web application

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, concurrenthashmap

I read lot of blogs and articles that ask to take care while coding for synchronization. They ask to use concurrentHashMap, synchronizedList etc.

As per my understanding, in java web application, Application server (e.g. jboss, weblogic, tomcat), every request run under a separate thread.

e.g. I have sequence of method execution method1--> method2--> method3, then every request will have its own execution stack. Then why do we need to think more about synchronization?

Either my understanding about concurrent request is not correct or I am missing something about synchronization scenarios.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in most applications, processing a request involves accessing some shared data that may also be accessed by other threads handling other requests at the same time.

HTTP sessions are a prime example:  all requests in the same session share the same `HttpSession` object, so if a browser sends two requests at the same time, the two threads handling those requests may try to access the same `HttpSession` object at the same time.  You need synchronization to avoid corrupting the session.

Comment: In more simple way --it may be a file, where few threads are reading data from it while few threads are writing data into the file.

Comment: Shared data is often kept in a relational database, and "synchronization" means careful use of database transactions to avoid exposing data in an inconsistent state.  (But this is really just a special case of @AnkitSharma's point about data stored in files.)

Comment: Yes I am completely agree with you. I just mentioned this point here cause new bie ll observe the things quickly.

Comment: "...shared data..."  And the point is, you need `synchronized` around every place where it is necessary for one thread to _temporarily_ put the shared data into a state that you would not want the other threads to see.